# Leaflet: make an array of array to feed in L.polyLine() method of leaflet javscript library

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, leaflet, maps, polyline

I am working on javascript leaflet library to draw dynamically generated coordinates and line between two such recent pairs. I have found that I can achieve that task using this code: 
`L.polyline(coordinatesArray, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);`

Here's definition of coordinates array:`var coordinatesArray=[];`

And whenver I get a new data,I push that in the array like this:

```
        coordinatesArray.push([coordinate[0],coordinate[1]]);
        L.polyline(coordinatesArray, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map); // line #107 as described in the error
        map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

I have run a raw code about how to feed and array in an array in javascript, for example:

```
var c=[];
 c.push([0,0]);
 c.push([1,1]);
 for(var i=0; i<c.length;i++){
   console.log(c);
 }
```

So, I think, I have implemented the `L.polyline(...,..)` method pretty well. But still getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at e.projectLatlngs (leaflet.js:8)
    at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
    at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addTo (leaflet.js:7)
    at (index):107
    at r.onmessage (stomp.min.js:8)
    at r.n.dispatchEvent (sockjs.min.js:2)
    at sockjs.min.js:2
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: You're passing `undefined` as the parameter for the `L.Polyline` constructor, somehow. Maybe a typo in the name of the variable?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I have found the problem:  my coordinates are being passed like this`["6.7", "2.5…"]`. I am trimming  both values before passing them. Even then I am getting that error.    The dots in` "2.5..."` are causing the problem first. Pls help fix this

Comment: You'll have to case those into `Number`s, and trace back when those values are converted into `String`s (and then prevent casting those into `String`s)

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thank you. That solved everything.